# using classes in same folder in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a class `test.ts`

```
export class Test1 {

}
```

I have another class `usetest.ts` in same folder that gives me error

```
import Test = require("test");//error say cannot find test
 var t = new Test.Test1();
```

but if I specify

```
 import Test = require("./test");//no error
     var t = new Test.Test1();
```

then there is no error. What the "./" is necessary? Can we omit it in anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What the "./" is necessary?

Yes

> Can we omit it in anyway?

Not easily. It needs to be in `./node_modules/test.ts` for `require('test')` to just work.

## More

Here is the complete nodejs module spec : https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together ... its a bit much but if you are doing NodeJS development I highly recommend reading it